# Java Web Services

Tags: java, web-services

I have a really basic question. I am new at Java WebServices. I want to use webservices to getting file names on server so I wrote below code; but I got an exception. Where is the mistake?

package gungor.webWord;

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "webWordWebService")
public class webWordWebService {

    /** This is a sample web service operation */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }

    /**
    * Web service operation
    */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getFileNames")
    public String[] getFileNames(@WebParam(name = "parameter") java.lang.String path) {
        File dir=new File(path);
        String files[]=dir.list();
        String fileNames[]={""};
        int j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if(!files[i].startsWith(".")){
                fileNames[j]=files[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return fileNames;
    }
}
```

Exception

```
Service invocation threw an exception with message : null; Refer to the
server log for more details


Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:330)
at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:106)
at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:133)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:301)
... 29 more Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: 1
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:134)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:123)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:144)
at $Proxy229.getFileNames(Unknown Source) ... 34 more Caused by:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at gungor.webWord.webWordWebService.getFileNames(webWordWebService.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:150)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:261)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:116)
at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:116)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:212)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:144)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:314)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:608)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:259)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:162)
at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:145) ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original cause of the exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at gungor.webWord.webWordWebService.getFileNames(webWordWebService.java:37) at
```

It's hard to tell without the line numbers, but this is one possible cause:

```
fileNames[j]=files[i];
```

... because fileNames[] is an array initialized with one element, therefore fileNames[j], where j == 1, would cause the exception shown in the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I did change fileNames[j]=files[i] line than problem solved. I did define a List and add string elements to it.